# Controlling fluctuations in a Markov chain

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

For $N>0$, consider the Markov chain $x_n$ on $\{0,1/N,...,1\}$ that moves up by $1/N$ at rate $(c-x_n/2)N$ and down by $1/N$ at rate $(c+x_n/2)N$.  As $N\rightarrow\infty$ sample paths approach solutions to the ODE $x' = -x$.  What I want to do is control fluctuations, which should be of size $1/\sqrt{N}$, so to have a statement like
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(\frac{1}{t}\int_0^tx_n > C/\sqrt{N}) \leq f(C,t)
\end{equation*}
where $f$ decreases quickly with $C$ and $t$.  I describe below the approach I am taking at the moment, but my question is, can this be done in an easier, cleaner way?

The approach I am taking now is to look at the discrete time chain $K_n$ on $\{0,1,...\}$ given by successive visits of $x_n$ to the levels $\{k/\sqrt{N}:k=0,1,...\}$ which has $p_{kk-1}/p_{kk+1} \geq e^{ck}$ for some $c>0$, and then to use some large deviations type estimates to control the frequency of visits to level $k$, for large $k$.  I then also have to control the amount of time it takes $x_n$ takes to move between levels.  It seems doable, but pretty messy.